# How to find where a function is being called from in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am Android Developer. I have started learning Laravel and I have a sample project that I am currently understanding. There are functions which are not being called from anywhere. This function has to be called on a event. On running the project the functions are called and working fine. How to know from where the functions are triggered.

I have searched the whole project for those functions and only can find one result where the function is declared, not from where its been called. I have looked in Event and Listeners  folders, but can't find anything. Please help I have to complete a project which has a soon approaching deadline.

```
public static function generateInvoice($user,$case){
   // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw exception inside that function and run it if you can do it by clicking on web app (or call request in other way) - if no then try to find in project source code by its name (multifile full text search).

```
throw new Exception('Test exception to get stacktrace');
```

or `new \Exception(...)`. This will show you stacktrace  as request result and/or you will find it in `storage/logs/laravel.log` file

Comment: When I added the line "throw new Exception('Test exception to get stacktrace');
" it didn't add anything in laravel logs however when I added some random uncompilable text into the function it did throw error which I can see in laravel log file. The Error is something  like "[2019-02-15 04:57:50] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\schoex\app\Http\Controllers\invoicesController.php:537
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  "

Comment: As it is event related function, I have to change date and again login into the website to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to terminal and run a grep query. That's how I mostly find things in an unknown project.

So go to terminal then, go to the app folder of the project:

```
cd root_of_the_pj_path/app
```

and then run a grep with the name of the function, like so:

```
grep -rlh 'generateInvoice('
```

It should list where the function has been defined as well as called/triggered.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: How is it any different from searching for "generateInvoice(" in Sublime Text. I assume grep -rlh is the equivalent of findstr in windows.

Comment: It's no different. So you are saying that you have searched "generateInvoice(" inside the app folder of the project and found only one occurrence where the function is defined?

Comment: Yes Exactly, there might be a possibility that the function is useless because when I print debug_backtrace inside it nothing prints. However when I insert some random characters it throws error.

Comment: You said in your question `On running the project the functions are called and working fine.`, now you are saying that its a possibility that the function is useless? Well, give it a try and run the search command in whole project, except "vendors" folder..see what you get